# No aparecen combobox ni DataEntry al ejecutar mi .exe en python

Tags: python

Hola soy nuevo programando y he realizado un primer programa pequeño para calcular una nómina usando python. Cree un modulo principal desde donde llamo a otros modulos para incluir, modificar, eliminar, calcular y generar un pdf con los resultados y al correrlo no se presenta ningun inconveniente ya que todo aparece como lo diseñe. Ahora al crear el ejecutable con el programa auyo-py-to-exe se me genera el ejecutable sin inconvenientes, pero al ejecutar el programa no me aparecen los Combobox en los modulos ni los Dateframe que utilizo para ingresar o modificar información, solo aparecen los Entry y Labels.

No se si mi error se presenta porque no se como incluir la libreria Reportlab y Tkcalendar en el programa auto-py-to-exe, ya que lo hice incluyendolo en -hidden-import de la opcion advance, solo colocandolo con el respectivo nombrede la libreria.

No coloco ningún codigo ya que me corre bien y solo se presenta el inconveniente luego de generado el ejecutable.

Espero que alguien pueda orientarme para resolver esto y poder poner en practica lo aprendido poco a poco en python.

Adjunto imagenes para que visualicen mejor el inconveniente que se me presenta.

Parte de programa sin convertir a .exe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte del programa luego de convertirlo a .exe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se mucho de auto-py-to-exe, pero puede que tus widgets no aparescan debido a un error de python que interrumpe el programa antes de crearlos. Prueba ejecutar tu exe en el cmd escribiendo en el input "eldirectoriodetuexe/ejecutable.exe" y si aparece un mensaje de error, agregalo en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Tampoco se de tu librería de interfaz grafica. Asi que el comentario de arriba es pura especulación. Sin embargo, no se pierde nada probando c:

Comment: si es por generar un exe hay muchas bibliotecas, a veces vale la pena probar otras.

Comment: Buenas Dante S., gracias por responder. Ejecute el programa desde el cmd y sigue con el mismo error de que no salen los combobos, los data Entry, pero al eejcutarlo desde python sin convertirlo a ejecutable si aparece todo.

Comment: BUenas tincopasan gracias por la respuesta. Que otra libreria me recomendarias a parte de ¨PYinstaller la cual ya use y me da error.

Answer (score 2):

Ya logre que aparecieron los combobox y demas entradas en el progama, para ello realice el ejecutable con otra libreria, especificamente cx-freeze, como me recomendo tincopasan.

Para eso cree el setup.py, donde packages lo deje en blanco y si me tomo las librerias reconocidas por python. Dejo el codigo para que lo observen por si alguno presenta este inconveniente y lo oriente:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("NOMINA.py",
                                 base = "Win32GUI",
                                 icon = indice.ico")]

build_exe_options = {"packages": [],
                     "include_files":["_init_.py",
                                      "calculo.py",
                                      "indice.ico",
                                      "recibos.py",
                                      "datos_mes.py",
                                      "lottt.py",
                                      "sueldos.py",
                                      "modificar.py",
                                      "incluir.py",
                                      "eliminar.py",
                                      "datos.py",
                                      "dias.py",
                                      "logoST.jpg",
                                      "BBDD_EMPRESA",
                                      "playa.png"]}

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "NOMINA",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Programa para calculo de Nómina",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = executables
    )
```

Imagenes ya corregido el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]